# How to write a Ruby-regex pattern in Java (includes recursive named-grouping)?

Tags: java, ruby, regex, netbeans, recursive-regex

well... i have a file containing tintin-script. Now i already managed to grab all actions and substitutions from it to show them properly ordered on a website using Ruby, which helps me to keep an overview.

Example TINTIN-script

```
#substitution {You tell {([a-zA-Z,\-\ ]*)}, %*$}
              {<279>[<269> $sysdate[1]<279>, <269>$systime<279> |<219> Tell  <279>] <269>to   <219>%2<279> : <219>%3} 
              {4}
#substitution {{([a-zA-Z,\-\ ]*)} tells you, %*$}  
              {<279>[<269> $sysdate[1]<279>, <269>$systime<279> |<119> Tell  <279>] <269>from <119>%2<279> : <119>%3} 
              {2}

#action {Your muscles suddenly relax, and your nimbleness is gone.}
{
    #if {$sw_keepaon}
    {
        aon;
    };
} {5}

#action {xxxxx}
{
    #if {$sw_keepfamiliar}
    {
        familiar $familiar;
    };
} {5}
```

To grab them in my Ruby-App i read my script-file into a varibable 'input' and then use the following pattern to scan the 'input'

```
pattern = /(?<braces>{([^{}]|\g<braces>)*}){0}^#(?<type>action|substitution)\s*(?<b1>\g<braces>)\s*(?<b2>\g<braces>)\s*(?<b3>\g<braces>)/im

input = ""

File.open("/home/igambin/lmud/lmud.tt") { |file| input = file.read }

input.scan(pattern) { |prio, type, pattern, code|
  ## here i usually create objects, but for simplicity only output now
  puts "Type    : #{type}"
  puts "Pattern : #{pattern}"
  puts "Priority: #{prio}"
  puts "Code    :\n#{code}"
  puts
}
```

Now my idea was to use the netbeans platform to write a module to not only keep an overview but also to assist editing the tintin script file. So opening the file in an Editor-Window I still need to parse the tintin-file and have all 'actions' and 'substitutions' from the file grabbed and displayed in an eTable, in wich I could dbl-click on one item to open a modification-window.

I've setup the module and got everything ready so far, i just can't figure out how to translate the ruby-regex pattern i've written to a working java-regex-pattern. It seems named-group-capturing and especially the recursive application of these groups is not supported in Java. Without that ***I*** seem to be unable to find a working solution...

Here's the ruby pattern again...

```
pattern = /(?<braces>{([^{}]|\g<braces>)*}){0}^#(?<type>action|substitution)\s*(?<b1>\g<braces>)\s*(?<b2>\g<braces>)\s*(?<b3>\g<braces>)/im
```

Can anyone help me to create a java pattern that matches the same?

Many thanks in advance for tips/hints/ideas and especially for solutions or (close-to-solution comments)!

Comment: Not quite answer to your question, but I would rather use proper parser (say, [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org)) for this kind of task anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text format seems pretty simple; it's possible you don't really need recursive matching.  This Java-compatible regex matches your sample data correctly, as far as I can tell:

```
(?s)#(substitution|action)\s*\{(.*?)\}\s*\{(.*?)\}\s*\{(\d+)\}
```

Would that work for you?  If you run Java 7, you can even name the groups. ;)

Comment: With Regex Tester and RegExr the pattern is only matching the #substitution blocks and ignoring the #action blocks.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the `(?s)` modifier, for DOTALL mode (what Ruby calls "multiline" mode).

Comment: thanks for giving me a possible solution to grab all the substitutions and actions from the file. although it doesn't also make sure all nested patterns are nested correctly i can fix that by some additional code once i have the group! kudos! and thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone help me to create a java pattern that matches the same?

No, no one can: Java's regex engine does not support recursive patterns (as Ruby 1.9 does).

Comment: i found that out already, but is there no way to reproduce the pattern without recursion?

Comment: Couldn't this be achieved by using the `Pattern` class to compile the regex and then creating a `Matcher` for the String, looping through to grab the groups that match it? I could be misunderstanding completely.

Comment: @Ingo, err, the pattern invokes itself making it (theoretically) match an infinite amount of nested matches. So no, that cannot be expressed with a regex engine that does not support recursion.

Comment: so i will have to end up using a non-recursive pattern, and then write additional code to validate correct nesting for each 'group' that can contain nested matches?

Comment: @Ingo, yes, if it is possible to do it with an engine that does not support recursive patterns (I know too little about the language you're trying to process).

Comment: @izuriel, if you (think you) know the answer, feel free to post it as such (and not just as a comment). :)

Comment: @BartKiers I may, but I figured I'd wait till I was somewhere to write/test sample code. :P

Comment: well this answer actually is correct in that so far i can't reproduce the pattern in java...